# URL_for can't find other view in flask blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to divide my flask website into multiple files, so I created blueprint in a file that I can just import into main. However, when I try running it, it finds the first view (chess_home) but when I submit, it can't find the next view (chess). It's specifically the URL_For function that doesn't work, when I just input into the browser all of the information manually, it works.

```
openings_guru = Blueprint('openings_guru', __name__, template_folder='templates')
@openings_guru.route("/chess/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def chess_home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.form["id"]
        color = request.form["color"]
        months = request.form['months']
        sort = request.form['sort']
        return redirect(url_for("chess", id=id, color=color, months=months, sort=sort))
    else:
        return render_template("chess.html")


@openings_guru.route("/chess/<id>/<color>/<months>/<sort>/")
def chess(id, color, months, sort):
```

```
[2021-05-08 12:33:16,332] ERROR in app: Exception on /chess/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/mattb/PycharmProjects/website/chess.py", line 59, in chess_home
    return redirect(url_for("chess", id=id, color=color, months=months, sort=sort))
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2216, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 358, in url_for
    endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=external
  File "/Users/mattb/miniconda3/envs/b529/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2179, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'chess' with values ['color', 'id', 'months', 'sort']. Did you mean 'home' instead?
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use blueprints, we also need to change url_for function, for example: `url_for("chess")` becomes `url_for("Chess.chess")` where Chess is name of the blueprint.